# Docker full with URL path

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pytorch, docker-build

Good day all,

Anyone knows if it's possible to just pull a single container from github? I do have this link `https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit` and I will like to pull the container in this link `https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit/tree/master/src/sagemaker_pytorch_container`.

I did try using build `docker build -t https://github.com/abc/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit.git` to just build an image of one file but there's an `init.py` file which i'm not sure if its necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a wrong path.

1. Github does not store docker images, so there is no way you can pull it from there.
2. AWS Sagemaker provides pre-built images, you just need to select the one you want to use when creating an instance. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/howitworks-create-ws.html
3. If you need a docker with `pytorch`, just run `docker pull pytorch/pytorch`

Comment: ohhhh i see! i had the wrong idea all along. I was always under the impression that Github stores the images and we could just pull it like Docker Hub. Thanks a lot for the clarification!